# Windows 10, 400 GB network data on "System" in the past 30 days

Tags: networking, windows-10

I've got a Windows 10 machine which, aside from playing some Mechwarrior Online from time to time, doesn't get heavily used.  I sometimes leave the PC on overnight.

In the past day, I've used 12 GB of data.  I don't stream movies or anything crazy like that.

In the past 30 days, my "System" application has used 419 GB of data.

How can I track and figure out what is causing this?

Check out the bottom entry for "System"

[image]

Comment: I guess only Microsoft knows for sure...

Comment: The issue ended up being malware that was removed using Malwarebytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the "System" use network to download Windows Update. Even so, for me it seems irregular to reach 419 GB. You can try other apps to track network traffic and compare it. Maybe it just a glitch in windows in measure network usage.

One freeware I recommend is [Networx](https://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) (it's now commercial apps since v6.0). It provides a similar usage list with a daily basis network usage report.

[image]

Comment: While the issue ended up being Malware... this software would help track the root cause. Thanks!